# Can I define events in Typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

Let's say I have a parent Component `app-main-console` and a nested component `app-console`. The nested component has a table. It's initial when the main component loads.

I want data to populate the table be fetched if user wants to see it. So there's a `input` property called `fetchTableData`.

```
<app-console [fetchTableData]="fetchTableData">          
</app-console>
```

It's a boolean.

```
@Input() fetchTableData: boolean;
```

Is it possible to define an event so that when the value of `fetchTableData` becomes `true`, I can call the backend service?

Thanks for helping

Comment: When the value of fetchTableData will become true?

Comment: When the user select the `right location` from a Select element. If the value is other than `empty string` then it's time to fetch data then expends the panel, which was collapsed. I'm supposed to send the selected value, but I'm sending a Boolean for now, just to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `OnChanges` from [Angular life cycle hook](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#onchanges).

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  for (let propName in changes) {
    if(propName === 'fetchTableData') {
      let chng = changes[propName];
      let cur  = chng.currentValue;
      let prev = chng.previousValue;

      if(cur && cur === true) {
        // Action you want to perform
      }

    }
  }
}
```